# How to stretch multiple images in Davinci Resolve to fill a blank space in a video

Tags: davinci-resolve

I am using Davinci Resolve. I would like to stretch a few images over an audio to fill the empty space. I was wondering if there is a systematic and quick approach to achieve this.

One easy solution would be to simply drag each photo or using some math, I can use a formula like:

the length of audio/the number of images

to find the appropriate length for each picture. But if there are too many images, then this would be cumbersome. I was hoping there is a nicer way to achieve this. I have included a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: What OS? You can do this in seconds in Apple Photos, or minutes in iMovie [with better control].

Comment: not able to test this theory at the moment but you could try selecting all the clips and pressing Ctrl + D or right click > change duration and change the duration accordingly. as i said, this might not work as im not able to test it at the moment